# Convert varchar to 3 (sometimes 4) chars in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I select data from a database. The values are (field name is ADR_KOMP_VL) :

```
4 , 61A, 100, 12, 58, 123C, 6 A, 5
```

I need to convert these values to 3 digits (except when there is a letter then it is 4)

So the converted values should be:

```
004, 061A, 100, 012, 058, 123C, 006A, 005
```

The rules are:

- Always 3 digits
- No spaces
- If the original value is less than three digits, put 0's in front of it.(The length is 3)
- If the original value contains a letter, put 0's in front of it (but the length is 4)

For the "no space" part I have this:

```
select REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ','')
```

The solution I have so far is:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ','')), 3)
```

But this only gives me the right length, when there is **no** letter in the value. My problem is how to handle the values with a letter in them??

Comment: Is the letter always at the end or can it be in front or middle of string? Take a look at REPLICATE function - it can help you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: Always at the end. Thanks for the link, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement:

```
SELECT (case when ADR_KOMP_VL like '%[A-Z]%'
             then RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ','')), 4) 
             else RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ','')), 3) 
        end)
```

Answer (score 2):

This only check if the last character is letter. Additional logic will be required if that's not the case

```
SELECT  REPLICATE('0', CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(ADR_KOMP_VL, 1)) = 0 THEN 4
                            ELSE 3
                       END - LEN(REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ', '')))
        + REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ', '')
FROM    TX
```

**EDIT** - actually this might work better, checks for whole `ADR_KOMP_VL` if it's numeric:

```
SELECT  REPLICATE('0', CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ', '')) = 0 THEN 4
                            ELSE 3
                       END - LEN(REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ', '')))
        + REPLACE(ADR_KOMP_VL, ' ', '')
FROM    TX
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/284d3/2)**